# How to show icon in Django?

Tags: python, django

I gave the script of the font awesome to my head of the HTML but it is showing the squares instead of the icons.
Code is :

```
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "all.css" %}">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "bootstrap.css" %}">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="{%static "style.css" %}">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Candal&family=Lora&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
      <title>Online yuridik xizmatlar</title>
      <script src="//code.jivosite.com/widget/pvNOxCEa74" async></script>
    <!--Font Awesome -->
       <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/6cd0e4d425.js"></script>
    <style>
      #loader{
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        background: #000000
        url('../static/contact/images/Infinity-1s-200px.gif') no-repeat center;
        z-index: 99999;
      }
    </style>
     
    </head>

     <div id="home-icons" class="my-5 text-center">
       <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-4">
            <i class="fab fa-telegram-plane fa-3x mb-3"></i>
            <h3>Telegramdagi kanal</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit, sapiente?</p>
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-4">
            <i class="fab fa-facebook-f fa-3x mb-3"></i>
            <h3>Facebookdagi sahifa</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit, sapiente?</p>
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-4">
            <i class="fab fa-instagram fa-3x mb-3"></i>
            <h3>Instagramdagi sahifa</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit, sapiente?</p>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
    
    
     <div id="bg-box" class= "text-center text-white">
       <div class="dark-overlay py-5">
         <div class="container">
           <h1>Bizni ijtimoiy tarmoqlarda kuzating</h1>
           <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius iure, officiis magni delectus corrupti dolorum?</p>
         </div>
       </div>
    </div>
<div class="about-icons pb-5 my-5">
  <div class="container text-white text-center">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card bg-danger p-4 my-4">
          <i class="fas fa-building fa-3x"></i>
          <h3>Sample</h3>
          <p class="m-0">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim adipisci quisquam voluptatum voluptatibus quas officiis.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card bg-dark p-4 my-4">
          <i class="fas fa-bullhorn fa-3x"></i>
          <h3>Sample</h3>
          <p class="m-0">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim adipisci quisquam voluptatum voluptatibus quas officiis.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card bg-danger p-4 my-4">
          <i class="fas fa-comments fa-3x"></i>
          <h3>Sample</h3>
          <p class="m-0">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim adipisci quisquam voluptatum voluptatibus quas officiis.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card bg-dark p-4 my-4">
          <i class="fas fa-box fa-3x"></i>
          <h3>Sample</h3>
          <p class="m-0">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim adipisci quisquam voluptatum voluptatibus quas officiis.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card bg-danger p-4 my-4">
          <i class="fas fa-credit-card fa-3x"></i>
          <h3>Sample</h3>
          <p class="m-0">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim adipisci quisquam voluptatum voluptatibus quas officiis.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card bg-dark p-4 my-4">
          <i class="fas fa-coffee fa-3x"></i>
          <h3>Sample</h3>
          <p class="m-0">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim adipisci quisquam voluptatum voluptatibus quas officiis.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my code and here you can find all the details of the icon section in the body and head tag. I tried with several ways but it is not getting I think smth I messed up in the code wait for your assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give more details like the place where you displayed the icons. It is most likely not the problem of the script, but the way you specified the icons. Chances are the icons you are trying to display are premium. Or you used `fa fas` instead of `fa fa` or something similar. Post the rest of the code for more specific answer.

Based on your edit, the font awesome link is to a previous version and does not have this syntax, so use `fa fa` instead of `fas fa` or `fab fa`.

Comment: Ok I will show you full html templates then by editing my question

Comment: No it is not premium

Comment: How did you obtain this "https://use.fontawesome.com/6cd0e4d425.js" link?